# cant initiate a loop while runing pyinstaller aplication

Tags: python, pyinstaller

i have a loop within a loop that is just an auto clicker

```
from pyautogui import *
import pyautogui
import time
import keyboard
import win32api, win32con

stop = 'n'
while stop =='n':
    time.sleep(2)
    while keyboard.is_pressed('q') == False :
        win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0)
        time.sleep(0.01)
        win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0)
    stop = input("stop ? n/y")
```

and when i try to make it an exe with pyinstaller

```
pyinstaller --onefile pythonScriptName.py
```

it just gives me an Application File but with a blank screen thet does nothing
how do i solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're asking for an input at the end of every while loop:

```
stop = input("stop ? n/y")
```

But since you don't have the terminal open, the script cannot get an input and the loop doesn't continue.

Edit: How I would solve this:

```
while true:   
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0)
    time.sleep(0.01)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0)
    if keyboard.is_pressed('c'): break
```

I didn't test it, but the code should look similar to that.

Comment: ok, so how am i supposed to open the terminal ? or have the loop work an other way?

Comment: You would have to use another way to terminate the script, for example by adding a statement like: if keyboard.is_pressed('c'): break. Edit: added example code.

Comment: it did not solve the problem wuth the application being black and not functioning and it just doesn't stop when you try to press the key while runing it as a .py file

Comment: Is that the whole code? Because I don't see why it would create a window. Try just running the file without converting it to an executable.

Comment: ok sorry for taking your time, both codes worked it just takes about 30 seconds for the loop to begin

Comment: No problem, is there anything else that is executed for it to take 30 seconds?